# How to check if a polynomial in $F[x]$ is irreducible or not, for $F$ a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I need to check the irreducibility of $p(x) \in F[x]$, where $F$ is a finite field.
I have read and checked on several exercises on the internet. Their solutions are as follows:

For instance, let $p(x)$ an arbitrary polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

If $p(x)$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, then they say that $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

*I am confused at this point:*  The polynomial $p(x)=(x^2+2)(x^2+3)$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$, but it is reducible? Where is my mistake?

Comment: You are not mistaken - in fact, you are correct. The solution is incorrect. Perhaps they meant to say that if $p(X)$ has no zeros in $F$ and $p(X)$ has degree $\leq 3$, then $p(X)$ is irreducible (do you see why this must be the case?).

Comment: Why does $p(x)$ have degree $\leq 3$ ?  If we consider $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, how to check the reducibility of $p(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

In $Z_5[x]$ the polynomial $p(x) = x^4 + 1$. This can be checked to have no zeroes in your field.

It seems the definition you are using is incorrect. Reducible means factorable into polynomials of lesser degree.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be an integral domain with unity, a polynomial $f(x) ∈ D[x]$ such that $deg(f(x)) ≥ 1$ is irreducible polynomial in $D[x]$, if whenever $f(x) = g(x) • h(x)$ then either $deg((g(x)) = 0$ or $deg((h(x)) = 0$.

There is one more thing which is irreducible element in Integral domains. Let $R$ be a CRU (commutative ring with unity) then an element $ a∈ R $ is called irreducible element, if

(i) $a ≠ 0$ and a is non-unit

(ii) whenever $ a= bc$ for some $b, c ∈ R$  then either $b$ is unit or $c$ is unit in $R$

For example: 
Consider, 
$f(x) = 2x^2 + 4∈Z[x] $ 
then $f(x) = 2(x^2 + 2) = g(x) • h(x)$ (say)
Then we saw that, $deg(g(x)) = 0$ so that $f(x)$ is irreducible polynomial in $Z[x]$ but it not an irreducible element in $Z[x]$, since neither $2$ nor $ (x^2 + 2)$ are units in $Z[x]$.

So "irreducible polynomial need not be an irreducible element" 
But when $F$ is field then "every irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ is an irreducible element of $F[x]$ and conversely"!

In fact you can check if you take 
$f(x) = 2x+ 2 ∈ Z_3 [x]$ then $f(x)$ has root in $Z_3$ but $f(x)$ is irreducible polynomial over $Z_3$